# Express.js + lint gives mistake

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, eslint

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fa4cRMaTDUI
I am watching this lesson and trying to recreate everything author does. At 19:00 he sets vue.js-express.js project. He creates folder called 'server'. In 'server/' he runs 'npm init -f'. Then 'npm install --save nodemon eslint', then he inits eslint. 
Then in package.json file he writes:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon src/app.js --exec 'npm run lint && node'",
    "lint": "eslint **/*.js"
}
```

Then in folder 'server' he creates folder 'src'. In 'src' he creates 'app.js'. And in 'app.js; there is a simple console.log('hello').
Then he runs 'npm start'. 'Hello' is printed in terminal, nodemon and eslint works just fine. Then he types 'npm install --save express'. Thats where my problem begins. After installing express.js i type 'npm start' and i get this error in terminal:

```
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 5.0.0.
No files matching the pattern "node_modules/ipaddr.js" were found.
Please check for typing mistakes in the pattern.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! server@1.0.0 lint: `eslint **/*.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 lint script. 
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional   logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/r/.npm/_logs/2018-06-25T10_32_02_027Z-debug.log
[nodemon] process failed, unhandled exit code (2)
[nodemon] Error
at Bus.utils.bus.on (/home/r/projects/tab-tracker/server/node_modules    /nodemon/lib/nodemon.js:148:25)
    at Bus.emit (events.js:164:20)
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/r/projects/tab-tracker/server/node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor/run.js:164:11)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:12)
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Looks like maybe it is trying to lint your `node_modules` directory. This should be ignored by default, but your wildcard `**/*.js` may be causing the issue. Try just using `eslint`

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Thank you. Do you have any idea why this would work for author? He seems to be using windows. Yesterday i tried to make this project on windows and i didn't have any problems with this part. Today i am using linux and it gave me this mistake. Is it posible that it caused by OS and different access rights?

Comment: not sure on that. I would say maybe the author was explicitly ignoring `node_modules` via an `.eslintignore` file but that doesn't explain why it worked for you on Windows

Comment: It could be a nuance between the difference of Linux & Windows,.. `node_modules/ipaddr.js` is a directory, but of course looks like a js file.  Maybe in Windows lint it's doing this check, but with Linux it's not.

Comment: Quote the pattern and it works fine `"lint": "eslint \"**/*.js\""`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@joknawe in comments gave right answer, thanks.
edit:

> Looks like maybe it is trying to lint your node_modules directory. This should be ignored by default, but your wildcard **/*.js may be causing the issue. Try just using eslint

Comment: You should write it as an complete answer, in the current state this is not really an answer.

Comment: Quote the pattern and it works fine `"lint": "eslint \"**/*.js\""`

Answer (score 27):

Quote the pattern and it works fine as in previous versions of eslint

```
"lint": "eslint \"**/*.js\""
```

Credit goes to
https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/10599

Comment: this fixed my issue without explicitly ignoring node_modules

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code

```
"start": "nodemon src/app.js --exec 'npm run lint && node'",
"lint": "eslint **/*.js"
```

for

```
"start": "nodemon src/app.js --exec 'npm run lint && node'",
"lint": "eslint"
```

Answer (score 2):

I use WSL and i fixed by changing following line.

Previous

```
"start": "./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js src/app.js --exec 'npm run lint && node'",
"lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint **/*.js"
```

After

```
"start": "./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js src/app.js --exec 'npm run lint && node'",
"lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint src/**/*.js --fix"
```

Answer (score 0):

In a Mac I fixed it just changing the following line

Previous

> "lint": ""lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint **/*.js""

After

> "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint src/*.js"

Answer (score 0):

Just add quotes around the wildcard `**/*.js`.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon src/app.js --exec 'npm run lint && node'",
    "lint": "eslint **/*.js"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in .eslint.js file you should replace this code

Before

```
"browser": true
```

After

```
"node": true
```